# What is needed to implement Jquery UI datetime picker with time slider

Tags: jquery-ui

Can someone please steer me in the right direction to implement Jquery UI datetimepicker with slider as described here:

http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/#basic_examples

I have found lots of materials from searches but I am confused as to exactly what is needed to integrate the datetimepicker in my web page:

Whats the exact css I need to link to on my web page?

Which specific jquery library should I include?

Which class should I specify on my input to get both the datetime + slider?

In my header I have something like:

```
<link href="//Content/bootstrap/css/jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-lib/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

Then the input:
 <input id="datetimepicker1" class="ui-datepicker" type="text" value="" name="datetimepicker1" />

Then scripts:
<script>

$("#datetimepicker1").datetimepicker();
</script>
```

Comment: post the code that you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

you need to include some extra css

```
  /* css for timepicker */
 .ui-timepicker-div .ui-widget-header { margin-bottom: 8px; }
 .ui-timepicker-div dl { text-align: left; }
 .ui-timepicker-div dl dt { float: left; clear:left; padding: 0 0 0 5px; }
 .ui-timepicker-div dl dd { margin: 0 10px 10px 45%; }
 .ui-timepicker-div td { font-size: 90%; }
 .ui-tpicker-grid-label { background: none; border: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }

 .ui-timepicker-rtl{ direction: rtl; }
 .ui-timepicker-rtl dl { text-align: right; padding: 0 5px 0 0; }
 .ui-timepicker-rtl dl dt{ float: right; clear: right; }
 .ui-timepicker-rtl dl dd { margin: 0 45% 10px 10px; }
```

put that in a file and include it eg datepicker.css

```
   <link href="datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

EDIT

I just realized you didnt include jquery-ui-xxx.js,
roll yourself a theme or download an existing one from http://jqueryui.com/ and include the script source in your html

Comment: Why wouldn't I need an input? I need the user to click inside the input box then the datetime picker pop up. When I include just the div nothing appears on my web page

Comment: Sorry, you're right about the input, i was thinking of a jquery-ui slider.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/ documentation, the requirements are jQuery and jQuery UI with datepicker and slider widgets. So you should include them like the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" type="text/css" href="jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
```

and write script like this

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#datetimepicker1").datetimepicker();
    });
</script>
```